# ES5 exported function not recognized

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I got this math.js:

```
const sum = (a, b) => a + b
const mul = (a, b) => a * b

export default { sum, mul }
```

then in math.test.js:

```
const { sum, mul } = require('./math')

test('Adding 1 + 1 equals 2', () => {
  expect(sum(1, 1)).toBe(2)
})

test('Multiplying 1 * 1 equals 1', () => {
  expect(mul(1, 1)).toBe(1)
})
```

I got this error from jest:

```
? Adding 1 + 1 equals 2

  TypeError: sum is not a function

    5 | })
    6 | test('Adding 1 + 1 equals 2', () => {
  > 7 |   expect(sum(1, 1)).toBe(2)
    8 | })
    9 |
```

If I import those function in the test file, jest runs fine.
Can't understand proper way to take external function in ES5.

Comment: Your mixing your module loading up,.  `require` is commonjs,  try using import instead.

Comment: ES5 doesn't have modules. They were introduced in ES2015 (sometimes called "ES6").

Comment: So were the arrow functions, by the way, that's another thing ES5-incompatible here.

Comment: sorry guys I've taken an online tutorial....anyways thanks i've caught the problem!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. This line probably doesn't do what you think it does:

   ```
   export default { sum, mul }
   ```
2. You're mixing native module syntax (`export`/`import`, often called "ESM" for **E**CMA**S**cript **M**odules) with CommonJS syntax (`require`). Use `import` to import in ESM syntax.

`export default { sum, mul }` exports a default export that's an object with the properties `sum` and `mul` (which would be an odd thing to do with ESM). If that's really want you want to do, fine, but it's not usually best practice. You can't destructure on import, but you can destructure the object after importing it:

```
// BUT YOU PROBABLY DON'T WANT TO DO THIS, KEEP READING
import math from "./math"; // Imports that default export
cosnt {sum, mul} = math;   // Destructures it into constants
```

**But**, normally you'd use named exports, either as you go:

```
export const sum = (a, b) => a + b
export const mul = (a, b) => a * b
```

...or all at once (style decision):

```
const sum = (a, b) => a + b
const mul = (a, b) => a * b

export { sum, mul };
```

To **import** named exports, you'd use syntax like you did but with `import`, not `require`:

```
import { sum, mul } from "./math";
```

That's not destructuring, though it looks similar. It lacks several features of destructuring (nesting, default values, ...).

Alternately you can import a *namespace object*:

```
import * as math from "./math";
```

That will have `sum` and `mul` properties on it (which is why you don't normally export an object with JavaScript native modules; anything that really wants one can get a namespace object).

Answer (score 3):

use `named export` :

```
export const sum = (a, b) => a + b
export const mul = (a, b) => a * b
```

**or**

```
export {sum,mul}
```

**then**

```
import { sum, mul } from './math'
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
const { sum, mul } = require('./math')
```

with

```
import { sum, mul } from './math'
```

Comment: `require` isn't the only problem here.

Answer (score 0):

You can leave your function declarations as is and change your export to `export { add, mul }`
and as was said above, change your `require` statement to `import`.

Comment: Please take the time to read answers that have already been posted before posting an answer, and don't just restate what previous answers have already covered, it just clutters things up.